# Using XSLT to Group Data Based on Substrings

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

I am trying to use XSLT to group data from an XML document into two categories. Specifically, given a list of three items, I want the XSLT to export the three items as two different groups (food & buildings). I'm attempting to do this by grouping the data by substrings.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items> 
    <Skyscraper>Willis Tower</Skyscraper> 
    <Small_fruit>blueberry</Small_fruit> 
    <Big_fruit>watermelon </Big_fruit> 
</items>
```

What I tried (XSLT):

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>  
    <xsl:template match = "/">      
        <items>
            <xsl:element name = "Fruit">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="//items" group-by="*[contains(local-name(), 'fruit')]">
                    <xsl:copy-of select = "."/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    <xsl:if test = "not(position() = last())">,</xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:element>
        </items>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I expected (XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items> 
    <Building>
        <Skyscraper>Willis Tower</Skyscraper>
    </Building> 
    <Food>
        <Small_fruit>blueberry</Small_fruit> 
        <Big_fruit>watermelon </Big_fruit> 
    </Food>
</items>
```

**Edited XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <!-- airport XSLT -->
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>  
    <xsl:template match = "/">      
        <items>
            <xsl:element name = "fruit">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="/items/*" group-by="*[contains(local-name(), 'fruit')]">
                    <xsl:copy-of select = "."/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    <xsl:if test = "not(position() = last())">&#xa;</xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name = "building">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="/items/*" group-by="*[contains(local-name(), 'sky')]">
                    <xsl:copy-of select = "."/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    <xsl:if test = "not(position() = last())">&#xa;</xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:element>
        </items>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why do you write you expect an `items` root element with two child elements `Building` and `Food` when your code creates a root element `items` with a single child named `Fruit`? And your grouping body contains an `<xsl:if test = "not(position() = last())">,</xsl:if>` which output a comma between groups while no comma is given in your expected XML. So your code doesn't make much sense, you might want to group e.g. `select="/items/*" group-by="contains(local-name(), 'fruit')"`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I edited it with your suggestions at the bottom of my post. I'm still having issues with the code pulling the content in the elements into the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/items">      
    <items>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="contains(local-name(), 'fruit')">
            <xsl:element name="{if(current-grouping-key()) then 'Food' else 'Building'}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </items>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

P.S. You could also do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/items">   
    <xsl:variable name="fruit" select="*[contains(local-name(), 'fruit')]" />   
    <items>
        <Building>
            <xsl:copy-of select="* except $fruit"/>
        </Building>
        <Food>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$fruit"/>
        </Food>
    </items>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The difference is this will always create both groups, even if one (or both) of them is empty.